# Can I allow a non-root user to log in when /etc/nologin exists?

Tags: users, login, shutdown, non-root-user

Suppose a non-root user with sudo privileges executes a delayed shutdown (`shutdown +10` or whatever) and logs out. Then, before the shutdown occurs, he wants to log back in and cancel the shutdown. The problem is that `shutdown` creates `/etc/nologin`, and `login` only allows root to log in when that file exists... is it possible to create an exception from this for a user?

If not, what would be the best way to let a user initiate a delayed shutdown, then logging in and cancelling it at a later point?

Comment: One could maybe use `shutdown now` with the `at` scheduler as a workaround.

Answer (score 21):

If your system uses [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules), the login denial when `/etc/nologin` exists is triggered by the [`pam_nologin` module](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_nologin.html).

You can skip the `pam_nologin` invocation for users matching certain criteria with [`pam_succeed_if`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_succeed_if.html). For example, if you want to allow users in the `adm` group to log in on a text console even if `/etc/nologin` exists, add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login` just before the line with `auth requisite pam_nologin.so`:

```
auth [default=ignore success=1] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup adm
```

Comment: This answer makes sense and matches what it says in the `man` pages for `pam.d` and `pam_succeed_if` perfectly, but doesn't work for me on Arch Linux 5.12.

Comment: This PAM option does not work anymore under OpenSSH 8.8p1 if `UsePAM no` option is used.

It would actually check the `/etc/nologin` after authenticated session has been established and TTY opened.

Answer (score 9):

Vesa K's version of Ryan Novosielski's answer works for me, but the lines are in:

```
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

not:

```
/etc/pam.d/login
```

In my case, I just want UID 1000 under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to be allowed to login via SSH.

```
# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid eq 1000
account    required     pam_nologin.so
```

Comment: Thanx for pointing out the separate pam.d/ssh configuration that may be needed.  I edited @Giles answer above to include it.  Some people don't read alt the answers before leaping into action...  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! In 22.04.1-Ubuntu it is "account".   For ssh - login you do not even need to alter /etc/pam.d/login Only /etc/pam.d/sshd was sufficient . This is good for security and prevents issues to be addressed from remote - like it!

Answer (score 4):

Gilles's answer above is very good, but note you must match the "type" with pam_nologin.so's type. So for example, on my RHEL5 system:

```
account [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup nx
account required     pam_nologin.so
```

...if I used auth, as the other answer requested, it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm sure this is accurate for when it was written and RHEL5 and when it was written. On my Arch system, the _type_ used for `pam_nologin.so` is `auth`. So, Gilles's answer would be more correct for me. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me on Arch Linux. I also tried changing the _type_ for both rules to `account`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible to override the `/etc/nologin` creation/usage without dirty tricks. But for your purpose, you can use a function like this:

```
off () { 
   touch /tmp/GOING-DOWN
   sudo sh -c "sleep ${1-1} && [ -f /tmp/GOING-DOWN ] && /sbin/poweroff"
}
```

Upon re-login, deleting the file `/tmp/GOING-DOWN` will prevent shutdown.

**edit**: Added a simple way to cancel the shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Ryan's rule today and found out that Gils's and Ryan's answers bot have success/default rules "reversed", nologin blocks only nx-group. This is how I implemented this rule (nx group is not blocked by nologin).

```
account [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup nx
account required     pam_nologin.so
```

Comment: The `man` page for `pam.d` doesn't say anything about the order of the values. It does refer to `default` as "the last of these", but I believe that's only referring to the order in which they appear in the `man` page. In any case, I tried the answers from Gilles, Ryan, and you without success on Arch Linux.